# Can I access menu items programmatically from a Cocoa app?

Tags: cocoa, macos

I'm talking about Mac OS X. Can I count the amount of menu items currently displayed for the active window? Can I get their text? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using the accessibility API.

Comment: And [the docs for doing this for any application's menus](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accessibility/Reference/AccessibilityCarbonRef/).

Comment: Thanks! Do I understand it correctly, that I need to invoke [element accessibilityAttributeValue:NSAccessibilityChildrenAttribute] and then go through the elements ask them for their role using [child stringValueForAttribute:NSAccessibilityRoleAttribute]?

Comment: Here is also some useful piece of technique: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178860/getting-window-number-through-osx-accessibility-api Thank to all of you guys!

Comment: Updated [link to the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/)